Do players keep getting norms even after obtaining their titles?
Do players keep getting norms even after obtaining IM, GM titles since norms are based on rating performances if I'm not wrong?
So does a GM keep getting IM and GM norms? For an IM getting GM norms is expected but is it the same for IM norms as well?


Do players keep getting norms even after obtaining IM, GM titles since norms are based on rating performances if I'm not wrong?

You are wrong. There is a lot more to getting a norm than a rating performance. Norms can only be achieved in norm tournaments. These are very different from regular tournaments, starting with the requirement that they be registered as norm tournaments with FIDE at least 30 days beforehand.
For a full description of the requirements see FIDE Title Regulations effective from 1 January 2024. Note that it is possible to play in a norm tournament, achieve the required rating performance and still not qualify for a norm because one of the other criteria has not been met.
These additional requirements include:

Level of arbiters (at least one FA or IA must be in the playing venue at all times)
Number of rounds
Playing schedule
Number of other titled players played
Number of other federations of players played
Maximum number of players played from the same federation as the player
Maximum number of players played from the same federation which is different from the players federation
PGNs of all games played in the tournament submitted to FIDE

Additionally, the chief arbiter has to fill in a norm report for the player, sign it and send it to the player's federation which then has to send it to FIDE for ratification. Of course, before doing so the arbiter has to check that all additional criteria have been met. If a player already has the title then nobody in their right mind is going to go through the final paperwork involved.
So, no, players who already have a particular title do not continue to receive norms for that title.

First off, a (achieving a) "norm" is a lot more than just a certain Elo performance. @BrianTowers pointed that out (along with detailed requirement information) already in his answer.
Still, his next-to-last sentence is mistaken:

If a player already has the title then nobody in their right mind is going to go through the final paperwork involved.

There are federations/countries which reward even titled players for fulfilling another norm of the title they already carry. I remember noticing somewhat bewildered that a friend (a greek GM) mentioned him fulfilling a norm. I asked him how that is relevant, he was already a GM at that time. "Yes", was his reply, "but we get some money from the state every time we make a norm, regardless of having the title already or not."

I think a case can be make that only GM with recent GM norms should count as GMs in norm tournaments.
